# How to get Youtube Rating into Div

Tags: php, api, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

this question has been asked before but it seems most of the posts are outdated and no longer functioning.

My request is simple. I need to pull the youtube rating of a video, get the likes and dislikes. The return the % of likes. So the likes divided by the total. This will update every time someone hits "next video".

Here is my code:

```
<!-- HTML DOCTYPE -->
<?php

$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $vid . '?v=2';

// get <yt:rating> node for like/dislikes
$yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
$attrs = $yt->rating->attributes();
$obj->dislikes = $attrs['numDislikes'];
$obj->likes = $attrs['numLikes'];
$total = (likes + dislikes);
$rating = (likes/total);
echo $obj->rating;
}
?>
```

Then it outputs here:

```
<div id="ratingNum" class="col-1-2 ps fl center">92%</div>
```